# Connecting to server with Proxy vs VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, proxy

Suppose I have a server and no-one can hack into my local area network. I want to Remote Desktop into my server from Internet. Exposing RDP is the most foolish thing I did do once and the server was brought down within days. I have configured IKEv2 now to get a local IP, but am regularly facing error 809, which goes away as soon as I restart Remote Access on Windows server. Now, my question is if I use RDP over proxy, am still vulnerable to attacks?

Answer (score -1):

You can first connect with VPN with your server network and then connect with RDP to your local PC.
I would not open the Port 3389. It is very dangerous.